# Sum of skew symmetric and symmetric parts of tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

Denoting the skew-symmetrisation and symmetrisation of a $(0,p)$-tensor $X_{a_1 \ldots a_p}$ by $X_{[a_1 \ldots a_p]}$ and $X_{(a_1 \ldots a_p)}$ respectively, is it always true that $X_{a_1 \ldots a_p} = X_{(a_1 \ldots a_p)} + X_{[a_1 \ldots a_p]}$?

Clearly, for $p=2$ this is true. I tried proving it for $p=3$ and I got:
$X_{(a b c)} + X_{[a b c]} = \frac{1}{3}(X_{abc} + X_{cab} + X_{bca})$ which seems to indicate that it is not true in this case. Is this correct, or have I gone wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decomposition only works for 2-tensors. It should be quite intuitive that you can't recover a general 3-tensor from its symmetrization and antisymmetrization - neither of these can distinguish $X_{112}$ from $X_{121}$.